# Include a DropDown in RadToolBarDropDown

Tags: html, asp.net, drop-down-menu, telerik

So I'm using Telerik's gui system and would like to insert a dropdown inside another one but I don't know how to do that.

This is what I've got so far

```
<telerik:RadToolBarDropDown runat="server" ToolTip="DropDown1" ImageUrl="~/Images/test.png">
    <Buttons>
        <telerik:RadToolBarButton runat="server" Text="Click me!" Value="TOGGLE_WALLS" CheckOnClick="true" ImageUrl="~/Images/checkmark.png"/>
    </Buttons>
</telerik:RadToolBarDropDown>
```

More or less, a dropdown inside a dropdown. Is it possible? Do Telerik support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an item template to nest a DropDownList or ComboBox in the RadToolBarDropDown:

```html
<telerik:RadToolBarDropDown>
    <Buttons>
        <telerik:RadToolBarButton>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="RadDropDownList1" runat="server">
                </telerik:RadDropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:RadToolBarButton>
    </Buttons>
</telerik:RadToolBarDropDown>
```